# JavaScript registering events handlers externally

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I have decided to remove all calls to JavaScript event from the html form elements to an external file. In doing this i registered an event for each item. However access the elements attributes using '`this`' can no longer be used what I have decided to use is `event.target.value` for value attribute and `event.target.name` for name attribute. I think this is not the best implementation since I am getting some adverse results from implementing it.

Under is my implemented code and more on the issue:

**JavaScript Inline Event Handler (Before)**

```
<input type="radio" name="rdb_NewUsers" value="1" list="#{'true':'Yes','false':'No'}" onclick="configureItemsForRadioButton(this.value, this.name)"
```

**JavaScript Registered External Event Handler (After)**

```
var configureRadioButtons = {           
            onClick:function(evt){
                evt.stopPropagation();
                console.log(evt.target.value + '||'+evt.target.name);
                configureItemsForRadioButton(evt.target.value, evt.target.name);
                
            }
    }; 
    dojo.connect(dojo.byId("rdbNewUser"), "onclick", configureRadioButtons, "onClick");
```

The problem I am facing is when I click on any button it actually executes the `console.log(evt.target.value + '||'+evt.target.name);` even though it is not an registered event for the button. I think using `event.target` refers to any event executed on the page. What else can be used instead of `evt.target.value` to refer to the object who fired the event's value and name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my code i soon realized i had overlooked something very important. My radio buttons actually carry a different id at run time `rdb_NewUserstrue` and `rdb_NewUsersfalse` and i was not registering events for these elements hence the reason the event kept firing on any click event, it was not finding an element with the id `rdb_NewUsers`. My solution is under:

I query the DOM for all radio buttons and got their `Ids` and based on the event/radio button clicked i attached a function (*all radio buttons are handled by one function*). In this way i did not need to hardcode an `id` for the radio button.

```
 var configureRadioButtons = {          
            onClick:function(evt){
                evt.stopPropagation();
                //console.log(evt.target.value + '||'+evt.target.name+ '||'+evt.keyCode);
                configureItemsForRadioButton(evt.target.value, evt.target.name);


            }
    };       


var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');  

for (var i = 0 ; i < radios.length ; i++){
    //console.log(radios[i].id);        
    dojo.connect(document.getElementById(radios[i].id), "onclick",configureRadioButtons, "onClick");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to avoid using a DOM manipulation tool like jQuery (which I do not recommend) you can do the following:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('Hello world');}, false);
```

If you use jQuery (recommended) it would work like so:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {alert('Hello world');});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what dojo.connect method does, but this is how you normally attach an event to an element on the page. From your code, it's hard to understand how exactly you are bind your events with the function.

```js
var configureRadioButtons = {
  onClick: function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e)

  }
};

document.getElementById("someID").addEventListener('click', configureRadioButtons.onClick, false);
```

```html
<button id="someID">Click me</button>
```